# How to save the Word Document using POI API?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi

how to save the Doc file using the same name using POI API

```
public class readDoc {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        String filesname = "Hello.doc";
        POIFSFileSystem fs = null;
        try {
            fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(filesname; 
            //Couldn't close the braces at the end as 
            my site did not allow it to close
            HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);
            WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);
            String[] paragraphs = we.getParagraphText();
            System.out.println( "Word Document has " +
            paragraphs.length + " paragraphs" );
            for( int i=0; i<paragraphs .length; i++ ) {
                System.out.println("Length:"+paragraphs[i].length());
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and i thought he was asking "how to save the world" :D

Answer (score 2):

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filesname);
doc.write(fos);
fos.close();
```

You could try writing to the `POIFsFileSystem` as well.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filesname);
fs.write(fos);
fos.close();
```