# Apache POI fails to save (HWPFDocument.write) large word doc files

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, doc

I want to remove word metadata from .doc files. My `.docx` files works fine with `XWPFDocument`, but the following code for removing metadata fails for large (> 1MB) files. For example using a 6MB .doc file with images, it outputs a 4.5MB file in which some images are removed.

```
public static InputStream removeMetaData(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    POIFSFileSystem fss = new POIFSFileSystem(inputStream);
    HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fss);

    // **it even fails on large files if you remove from here to 'until' below**
    SummaryInformation si = doc.getSummaryInformation();
    si.removeAuthor();
    si.removeComments();
    si.removeLastAuthor();
    si.removeKeywords();
    si.removeSubject();
    si.removeTitle();

    doc.getDocumentSummaryInformation().removeCategory();
    doc.getDocumentSummaryInformation().removeCompany();
    doc.getDocumentSummaryInformation().removeManager();
    try {
        doc.getDocumentSummaryInformation().removeCustomProperties();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // can not remove above
    }
    // until

    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    doc.write(os);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    return new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
}
```

Related posts:

- [How to save the Word Document using POI API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484906/how-to-save-the-word-document-using-poi-api)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758955/saving-poi-document-correctly

Comment: I don't get your problem to be honest. Is the problem, that you have some exception, or is it that you have too big output file => something to be removed is still left?

Comment: Metadata are removed correctly, but given a 6mb file with tables, footer, header and images, poi outputs a ~4.5mb file with metadata removed, but also some random images removed as well.

Comment: If random images are removed (each invocation removes something else), then it must be a threading issue, or an improperly handed outofmemoryerror for example. Threading issue can be checked, if you run it in a single thread, and it works properly then. Outofmemory error can be found with brakepoints. I suggest to run the code with debug mode, and set an exception brakepoints (catched and uncatched as well) to catch errors and RuntimeExceptions. Maybe you find something interesting.

Comment: If you could upload an example doc file, and your JVM arguments and JVM type, POI version, we could do more.

Comment: Here is a sample file in which some images get deleted. https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B04nNVcbjeicenliLW5zSElSdk0

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Apache POI are you using ?

This seems to be the [Bug 46220 - Regression: Some embedded images being lost](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46220) .

Please upgrade to the [latest release of POI (3.8)](http://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-3.8) and try again.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I used both poi 3.8 and latest nightly builds. Both have the bug.

Comment: Then, it is another bug, or a regression of the regression :/